# problem with clearing cart items in Reactjs application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, onclick, e-commerce

I am new to the Reactjs development side and to understand and have a complete understanding of reactjs i have started working on the ecommerce application.
I have finished with the display of products page with the help of .JSON file.
So with that i used those id's of the products and i was able add the particular item to the cart and remove them.

*****The problems I am unable work with are**:***

1. remove single item from cart when I have multiple products of similar product.
2. After adding the necessary products, I want to close the order and clear cart items for the next order but I am not able to do.

**Help needed with**

1. I want to clear cart items meanwhile storing the ordered items.
2. In removing only 1 product at a time when there are similar products with more than 1.

**For reference**
Github link for code: https://github.com/BhupathiVenkataSaiCharan/reactredux/tree/master/src/Redirects/Fvdata

> In Fvdata, I have my list of products in data.json
> In Fvdata > App.js , I have the use of click functions for Adding and removing the cart items.

Answer (score 0):

I check your code and from what I understand you have to tweak these two methods on your App.js file

```
removeFromCart=(product)=>{
    const cartItems = this.state.cartItems.slice();
    this.setState({
        cartItems: cartItems.filter(x=>x.id !== product.id),
    });
    localStorage.setItem("cartItems",JSON.stringify(cartItems.filter(x=>x.id !==product.id)));
}

clearCart=()=>{
    const cartItems = this.state.cartItems.slice();
    this.setState({
        cartItems: cartItems.filter()
    })
}
```

into this

````
removeFromCart=(product)=>{
    const cartItems = this.state.cartItems.slice().map(x => {
           if(x.id === product.id){
            return {
                 ...x,
                 count: x.count -1
               }
           }
         return x
        })filter(x=>x.count > 0);

    this.setState({cartItems});
    localStorage.setItem("cartItems",JSON.stringify(cartItems));
}

clearCart=()=>{
    this.setState({
        cartItems: []
    })
    localStorage.setItem("cartItems",JSON.stringify([]));
}```
````

Comment: I have changed those two as per your suggestion. For remove functionalty it is same as before the similar product is getting removed. For the other one i have a error about cartitems is not used